# Using ffmpeg to convert mp3 to mp4 - how to draw filename on generated video?

Tags: ffmpeg

Using trial and error I am using the following script on an OSX, to bulk convert a whole folder full of mp3 files, to mp4, by looping a specific video file:

```
for i in *.mp3; do /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i /path_to_filename.mp4 -c copy -v 0 -f nut - | /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 10K -i - -i "$i" -c copy -map 0:v -map 1:a -shortest "$(basename "$i" )".mp4 ; done; for f in *.mp3.mp4; do mv -v "$f" "${f/.mp3.mp4/.mp4}"; done
```

How can I also print/add/burn the mp3 filename, without the extension (.mp3), as an additional video layer at the bottom of the generated video screen, and with the added difficulty of word wrapping the text if is too long?

Answer (score 0):

This command makes a temporary SRT file for the [subtitles filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles) which will automatically deal with the placement and word wrapping:

```
for i in *.mp3; do echo "1" > subs.srt; echo "00:00:00,000 --> 10:00:00,000" >> subs.srt; echo "${i%.*}" >> subs.srt; ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i video.mp4 -i "$i" -filter_complex "[0:v]subtitles=subs.srt:force_style=Alignment=3,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 1:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -shortest -movflags +faststart "${i%.*}.mp4"; done
```

- Running the command in the directory containing the file allows avoidance of `basename` and creates a simpler command.
- MP3 is not universally supported in MP4. Consider changing `-c:a copy` to `-c:a aac` if your player does not support it. But I suspect you're targeting YouTube which will be fine with MP3 in MP4.
- The three instances of `echo` are inefficient but effective in avoiding any newline issues. Using one instance of `printf` would be more optimal, but I don't have access to macOS to test its `printf` implementation.